# IOS Custom sliding UIViewcontroller from left to right and caused segue error

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Due to I have to slide UIViewController from left to right by a finger swipe, I have created a custom uiviewcontroller transition, after slide and clicked the navigation inside the destination controller, error occurred.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'stepsPage'.
>   Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by
>   an instance of UINavigationController.'

```
- (void) returnHome
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.storyboard;

    MainViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
    // Get the views.

    UIView * toView = destVC.view;
    UIView * fromView = self.view;

    // Get the size of the view area.
    CGRect viewSize = fromView.frame;

    // Add the toView to the fromView
    [fromView.superview addSubview:toView];

    // Position it off screen.
    toView.frame = CGRectMake( -320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);

     NSLog(@" viewSize.origin.y %f", viewSize.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:
     ^{
         // Animate the views on and off the screen. This will appear to slide.
         fromView.frame =CGRectMake( 320 , viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
         toView.frame =CGRectMake(0, viewSize.origin.y, 320, viewSize.size.height);
     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (finished)
         {
             // Remove the old view from its parent.
             [fromView removeFromSuperview];

             //I use it to have navigationnBar and TabBar at the same time
             //self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row+1;

         }
     }];


    NSLog(@"swipe");
}
```

Segue Function in the destination view controller

```
- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{


    GeneralViewController *GeneralView = (GeneralViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    NSString *titleString;
    // Set the photo if it navigates to the PhotoView
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"stepsPage"])
    {
        titleString = @"Steps";

        GeneralView.goalStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [mySetting integerForKey:@"dailyStep"]];
        GeneralView.currentStr = [NSString stringWithString:_stepLabel.text];
        GeneralView.percentage = grpPercent.step;
    }

    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: show the code where your are pushing "stepsPage" segue, also show the storyboard screenshot for more clear picuture of problem

Comment: If you are using push then steps page view has to be embedded in navigation controller, otherwise you can use modal and that would work.

Comment: Beat me to it XCode Monkey ;)

Comment: how can I embedded in navigation controller when using the code above?  I can't use push or modal, bcoz the controller must slide from left to right.thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error you are getting you dont have Naviation Controller around controller through which you want to push it to next controller

Below approaches can be applied to such situation

**Approach 1 - Visually add Navigation Controller**

You need to your first controller or your existing controller must be embedded in UINavigation 
controller - you can do it in xcode 5 by going to Editor -> EmbedIn -> Select Navigation Controller

If you dont want Navigation to appear in your app you can use below line

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden =YES;
```

**Approach 2 - Programatically add Navigation Controller**

if you want to do it programatically you can do it as follows

```
MainViewController *destVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];

UINavigationController* navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:destVC];
```